# find received data in socket program

Tags: c#

im doing a network programs using Socket.
im receiving files and texts through Sockets as bytes,
after receiving it i want to find what i received (i.e)file or text

```
              thanx in advance.
```

Comment: Without a little more information this is hardly a real question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't force the sender to provide you with a header to tell you what sort of thing they are sending, then all you have are the bytes to look at and try to work out if it is binary or text. You could try decoding the bytes using UTF8 to a string. If there are a large number of non-ASCII characters in the string, it is probably not an English text file - but then you could be receiving Chinese for all I know.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to identify types is through the [internet media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) (a string identifying the general and particular type e.g. `image/jpeg`).

As you're transmitting the file/text through sockets via a byte array, I would (perhaps) transmit the appropriate internet media type at the beginning of the byte array - i.e. as a part of the complete byte array identifying what's coming.

But are you reinventing the wheel ? Is HTTP of use here ? It will handle the content and the type for you.